# division to zero handling excel

Tags: excel, error-handling, excel-formula

So I have a table like this:

```
Element Rate

Apple       3
Apple       4
Banana      2
Banana      0
Ananas      0
Ananas      0
Kiwi      (empty)
```

I want to find a average of the elements when it is above 0, when all 0 to get 0  and when cell is empty/blank to return n.a.

The core part of the formula I use is something like this :

```
AVERAGEIFS(Overview[Rate];Overview[Element]; D61;Overview[Rate]; ">0")
```

which gives me division to zero error, when all my values are 0 in the table such as if I want to find average for the Ananas,  I thought this might work and the error I would get from in case of the empty cell I could just use IFERROR function to return "n.a.", but stucked, what is the reason for this and how can it be solved?

Comment: Wrap your function with ifferror(your-function,0)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I need

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I said wrap your function in an iferror as shown:
[image: example]